# Removing "\" from URL in iOS Swift

Tags: ios

I am trying to fetch some Image feeds in iOS Swift App. But the Feed URL sometimes has **"\"**, **"/"**.
For example:

> http://lionsports.net/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_prefix=rp_primary&image_path=/images/2014/11/16\ /mbb_DeVonteUpson_3.jpg

I need to remove that "\" from "\ /". How can I achieve this?

*Note: There is no space between "\" and "/" but I kept it because this Editor automatically removes "\"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**str** - consider this is your url string

`let newStr = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\/", withString: "/")`

Comment: It should be `"\\/"`.

Comment: Agreed with you @tia.